# Is there a ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a ring homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Also for any rings $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ does there exist a ring homomorphism  $\phi$ : $R_{1} \rightarrow$ $R_{1} \times R_{2}$?

Note: I am allowing 1 in both rings. So any homomorphism must map the identity on one ring to the identity on the other ring.

Comment: Well there's the zero map, but I'm assuming you're talking about unital maps?

Comment: Since $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic, any isomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Z \to R$ is determined by $\phi(1)$.

Comment: If by unital you mean those that send 1 to 1 then yes.

Comment: with $\mathbb{Z}^2$ you meant $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ?

Comment: @Travis does that necessarily imply existence of $\phi$? Could you give an example?

Comment: @user1952009 Doesn't $\Bbb Z^2$ mean $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$? That's not the same ring as $\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: @arctictern I don't know, I was asking what are $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ (and $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ !) in the context of rings

Comment: @user1952009 As answers given since you asked have pointed out, for any unital ring $R$ there is a canonical ring homomorphism (which need be neither injective nor surjective) $\phi: \Bbb Z \to R$ defined by $$\phi(n) := \underbrace{1_R + \cdots + 1_R}_n .$$ Since $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic, this is the only homomorphism that maps $1$ to $1_R$.

Comment: @Travis : I know that

Comment: @user1952009 That answer was supposed to be directed to the similarly-named user105886---sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Travis : ok sorry to be named 'user' then, if you have ideas on what are the rings we can consider from $R$ and whose set of elements is $R \times R$ ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean, given a unital ring $R$, how can one classify the identity-preserving homomorphisms $R \to R \times R$? Note that there is always at least $1$, namely the diagonal map $\Delta(r) := (r, r)$.

Comment: @user1952009 the underlying set of $R\times S$ is the cartesian product of rings $R$ and $S$, with operations $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$. This is learned very shortly after learning the definition of a ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $R$, $S$ and $T$ are rings. Giving a ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S\times T$ is the same as giving homomorphisms $g\colon R\to S$ and $h\colon R\to T$.

Let's see why. First, the projection maps $p\colon S\times T\to S$ and $q\colon S\times T\to T$ are ring homomorphisms, so if we are given $f\colon R\to S\times T$, we get $p\circ f\colon R\to S$ and $q\circ f\colon R\to T$.

Suppose instead we are given $g\colon R\to S$ and $h\colon R\to T$. Define
$$
f(x)=(g(x),h(x))
$$
It's easy to see that $f$ is a ring homomorphism and that $g=p\circ f$, $h=q\circ f$.

In general terms this is the statement that $S\times T$ is the *product* in the category of rings.

This answers your second question: in order to have a ring homomorphism $R\to R\times T$ you need a ring homomorphism $R\to T$ (and use, for instance, the identity as the homomorphism $R\to R$). So, for a counterexample find rings $R$ and $T$ such that there is no ring homomorphism $R\to T$; take $R$ to have characteristic $2$ and $T$ to have characteristic $3$, for instance.

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, it's a standard result that, for any ring $R$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ (when unital rings are concerned and homomorphisms are required to preserve the identity element).

Comment: nice!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

For any ring $R$ there is a unique homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ defined $\phi(1)=1_R$. This is unique because then $\phi(n)=n\cdot 1_R$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The category theoretic term for this is that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object in the category of rings.

Comment: Is there a homomorphism defined in the same way for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow X$ for a ring $X$

Comment: Not quite, because a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to X$ is no longer determined by $\phi(1)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 that mean only one ring  homormorphism from $\mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ .Am  i right ?

Comment: @jasmine: yes, that is a special case of the uniqueness statement in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second question:

There is no homomorphism $\mathbb Z_5\rightarrow \mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z$.

This is because the image must be isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb Z_5$, and is therefore finite. On the other hand it contains $n(1,1)$ for every $n$, this gives us an infinite number of elements.